# Include multiple figures with knitr::include_graphics() in a single chunk an each figure with its own label (A, B, C, ...)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, ggpubr, cowplot

I would like to include several jpg/png figures side by side and *each labeled by a letter (A, B, C, ...)* in a Rmarkdown report compiled to both PDF and HTML.

[image]

Including the figures side by side is easy with `knitr::include_graphics()` and setting `out.width='100%/N'` for `N` figures:

````
```{r foo-label, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align = "center", fig.cap='(ref:foo-caption)', fig.scap='(ref:foo-scaption)'}
fig1_path <- paste0(fig_path,"Fig1.jpg")
fig2_path <- paste0(fig_path,"Fig2.jpg")
fig3_path <- paste0(fig_path,"Fig3.jpg")

knitr::include_graphics(c(fig1_path, fig2_path, fig3_path), auto_pdf = TRUE)
# if auto_pdf = TRUE: includes PDF version of figure if available in same folder
```
````

However, `include_graphics()` does not offer to label each figure by a letter (or even number).
This can easily be achieved with `cowplot` or `ggpubr` as follows:

````
```{r foo-label, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align = "center", fig.cap='(ref:foo-caption)', fig.scap='(ref:foo-scaption)'}

library(cowplot) # for ggdraw() & draw_image()
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

fig1_path <- paste0(fig_path,"Fig1.jpg")
fig2_path <- paste0(fig_path,"Fig2.jpg")
fig3_path <- paste0(fig_path,"Fig3.jpg")

# scale down all figures proportionally size to increase space between them
scaling <- 0.9
fig1 <- ggdraw() + draw_image(fig1_path, scale = scaling)
fig2 <- ggdraw() + draw_image(fig2_path, scale = scaling)
fig3 <- ggdraw() + draw_image(fig3_path, scale = scaling)

# cowplot style:
cowplot_plot <- plot_grid(fig1, fig2, fig3, labels = "AUTO")
cowplot_plot

# ggpubr style:
ggarrange_plot <- ggarrange(fig1, fig2, fig3,
                            labels = "AUTO", # add tag label to each plot
                            align = c("hv") #"none" = default
                            )
ggarrange_plot
```
````

The problem is that the resulting PDF file is 20x larger than the `knitr::include_graphics()` version.
Would anyone know how to use `knitr::include_graphics()` to include multiple figures side by side in a single chunk and each figure labeled with a letter?

Comment: How were the images created in the first place? If you have the control, it might be best to do all the labeling during that process.

Comment: Images are of various types (photographs, digital/scanned sketches, ...). If feasible I would like to refrain from the option to add the labels in another program manually. Also, when the figure order is changed, all labels require manual updating in this case.

Comment: Sub-figures are supported only in PDF output: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-subfigure.html

Comment: @YihuiXie Thank you for the input. Going as far as a subfigure with a separate caption is not even needed, a simple "A", "B" and "C" next to the top of each included figure would do, see the sketch added.